# Parameter in Controller Null After Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

**Here is the scenario:**

When a user selects the `Details` button, the JavaScript function, `getPersonId` grabs the personId as expected.

**Where the issue occurs:**

After selecting the `personId` I send that `Id` into an `ajax` call. The `Id` get's passed, but run into issues: **what should my success be?** and **the personId getting passed to the controller is null**

> **List of issues:**
>
> 1. How does Success work when sending a parameter to the controller?
> 2. The C# parameter is null.
> 3. What is the best way to call the ajax method? Should this be called on the details button click?

**Html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Details</th>
            </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            @foreach (var viewModel in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                   <td>@viewModel.Name</td>
                   <td>@viewModel.Age</td>
                   <td><button data-id="@viewModel.PersonId" type="button" data-bind="click: getPersonId" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-modal"><span class="fa fa-external-link-square"></span> Details</button></td>
                 </tr>
            }
       </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

**Creating PersonViewModel instance at bottom of HTML**

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            window.viewModel = new PersonViewModel().init(@Html.Json(Model));
        });
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function PersonViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.init = function(data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
        ko.applyBindings(self, $("#tblPerson")[0]);

        return self;
    }

    self.getPersonId = function(vm, ev) {
        var personId = $(ev.target).data('id');
        return personId;
    }

    self.getPersonEntity = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Person/RetrievePersonEntity',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ko.toJSON(self.getPersonId),
            success: function() {}  // not sure what I need here...
        });
    }
}
```

**C# Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RetrievePersonEntity(string personId)
{
    var result = _personOrchestrator.RetrievePersonEntity(personId);

    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: try using new js object like var obj={}; obj.personId="1"; and then pass as data

Comment: @rashfmnb I'm new to js so could you expand on this?

Comment: i mean to say instead of sending ko.toJSON(self.getPersonId) create new object instance like var newobj={}; obj.personId=self.getPersonId; and then send  data : ko.toJSON(newobj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 self.getPersonEntity = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Person/RetrievePersonEntity?personId=' + self.getPersonId(vm, ev),
            data: ko.toJSON(self.getPersonId),
            success: function() {
                return self.getPersonId
            }  
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Like this

```
self.getPersonEntity = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Person/RetrievePersonEntity' ,
        data: {personId:self.getPersonId(vm, ev)},
        success: function() {
            return self.getPersonId
        }  
    });
}
```